# Converting TIR data (CSV) to Raster layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, csv

I have thermal infrared data from a FLIR camera. I would like to be able to import this to Q with spatial reference and temperature data as a raster. Does anyone have experience with flir radiometric images?

Comment: Can you add a link to some specifications of such imagery?

Comment: Does the tir/csv data have x/y coordinates per feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not x/y coordinates per pixel. I do have a gps coordinates for each image/picture taken.